# Exchange 2010 and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I went through a painful Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 migration and faced a new problem - the utility I used for Active Directory management does not support Exchange 2010. Please advice a piece of software that could help (I run network for less than 1000 users).

Features I need to be included:

Establish, remove mailboxes, remove Exchange-specific properties from AD objects, provision mailboxes. (web interface would be a plus)

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the Exchange System Manager or Exchange Shell? Then you've got standard Active Directory Users and Computers for "normal" stuff...

Comment: Ben. I always keep ESM in mind, but it does not provision mailboxes. And I'm tired of switching between several tools for AD and Exch. In case there's no such software, ESM is the solution, of course. Thank you!

Comment: @hellbent - can you please clarify for me what you mean by "provisioning mailboxes". I probably know what you mean but my brain can't quite work it out!

Comment: Automatic mailbox creation right after creation of a user. Only scripts can solve this, I assume.

Comment: The **New-Mailbox** cmdlet will do that, as will the Exchange System Manager GUI.

Comment: I probably ought to stop calling it Exchange System Manager really. It's Exchange Management Console now. *Bangs head on table to try and make it sink in*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adaxes](http://www.adaxes.com) - their new version supports Exchange 2010, automates mailbox creation. But this is paid software, though it has free evaluation period. Consider Exchange System Manager & PowerShell first.

Comment: Thank you. I needed one console to deal with everything.

Answer (score 1):

What tool are you using?

If you are using a third-party tool, contact the vendor.  They may have an update, however it may require a paid upgrade since you *did* upgrade your infrastructure application.

What about the included Exchange System Manager?  That's what it's designed for?  If that is what you're using, you'll need to install the 2010 version.

Finally, don't neglect Powershell and PowerGUI.  Scripting is powerful.

Comment: I used manageengine. They stopped on 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft removed the Exchange integrations for Active Directory Users & Computers as of Exchange 2007. If you had the Exchange 2003 plugins, they kind of worked for reviewing settings but shouldn't have been used for changing things. Exchange System Manager and the Exchange Powershell are the methods Microsoft recommends for managing Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

> Establish, remove mailboxes, remove
>   Exchange-specific properties from AD
>   objects, provision mailboxes. (web
>   interface would be a plus)

Theses are all tasks that can be accomplished via the native tools that come with exchange 2010 and or basic windows tools.  For instance to create a new user in AD and create a mailbox you would use the [new-mailbox cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663.aspx), as nother example to remove the properties (  I suspect you are refering to the old "remove exchange attributes" option in 2003) use `disable-mailbox -Identity Windows.Username` from within the management shell.

I would suspect that the reason the tools you were using do not have updates is because they are simply no longer needed as the functionality is easy enough to accomplish with the native tools.